# Android : How to get Dynamic EditText values

Tags: android, android-edittext

In my application I'am creating 10 EditText by dynamically. Now I want to give different value in run time and I want to add it to the list. I have assigned EditText object to the String variable like object.getText.toString(). But i cant get any value.I'am a beginner in android. Can anyone help me how to achieve this? Thanks in advance.

```
for(int i=0;i<=10;i++)
{
requirement = require.get(i);
RelativeLayout rl1 = new RelativeLayout(getActivity());
rl1.addView(req1);
req1estimate_value = new EditText(getActivity());
String value = req1estimate_value.getText().toString();
rl2.addView(req1estimate_value);
}
```

Comment: You haven't applied any input to your `EditText` so always it will be  null.

Comment: req1estimate_value = new EditText(getActivity(??));  pass some values or param stating some values in it

Comment: @Naufal req1estimate_value.setText("10"); If i give like this then it prints 10 in all the EditText. But i want to give value at runtime and i want to add all the values in a list. Could you give me small example?

Comment: @PiyushGupta Could you give me small example?

Comment: your input is from edittext, that is stored in value string.. try passing that like this.... req1estimate_value = new EditText(getActivity());
String value = req1estimate_value.getText().toString();
rl2.addView(value);

Answer (score 1):

Try this. You should instantiate relative layout (rl1) at out of `for` loop, and should add child views with in that, so that all views could belongs to a parent layout. After that for accessing the values of all `EditText` you can use following:

```
String viewValue;
ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) rl1;
int count = rootView.getChildCount();
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
     View view = rootView.getChildAt(i);
     if (view instanceof EditText) {
                    viewValue = ((EditText) view).getText().toString();
                    Log.v("Value:: ", i + " " + viewValue);
                } else if (view instanceof Spinner) {
                    viewValue = ((Spinner) view).getSelectedItem()
                            .toString();
                    Log.v("Value:: ", i + " " + viewValue);
                }
    }
```

Now after getting values you can put on a List or anywhere you want to use.